# django models: get list of id

Tags: sql, django, django-models

How do i get a list of all id/primary key for a table. Say i have this table:

```
class Blog(models.Model)
  title = models.CharField()
  body = models.CharField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

assume the field *author* is an Author object. I want to get all the ids of Blog where author=author

i know i can use

```
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(author=author)
```

and get all the blog objects in a list form, but how do i get the list IDS/PK? Similar to "Select id from Blog where Author=author"

Comment: I am curious why you want this? Usually you don't deal with the primary key as its managed by django.

Comment: @burhan its kinda complicated, i need to use the list of PK/ID for another query, w/c is something like `not_authored_blog = Author.objects.exclude(blog__id__in=blogs)`. i have another table which has FK to 'blog' and want to get the objects in the other table that is not FK in 'blog'. more complicated than that though

Comment: You can get around this by checking if the `blog_set` related manager has any records; if its empty, then this Author has no blogs. It will be a lot better than doing your exclude query, which might be translated as a large `NOT IN` clause.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can do this using [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method.

```
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(author=author).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

See more at the [Django queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: Is there any way to get those ids without parse the returning queryset? I get <QuerySet [13, 14, 15]> and I want that list of ids. Is any pythonic way to avoid iterate over the rows?

Comment: list method get ids without parse the returning queryset. print(list(ids))

Answer (score 78):

```
Blog.objects.filter(author=author).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

`values_list()` gives a list of rows, each row a tuple of all of the fields you specify as arguments, in order. If you only pass a single field in as an argument, you can also specify `flat=True` to get a plain list instead of a list of tuples.

Comment: It is best to use `pk` instead of `id`, the internal value `pk` will always point to the primary key field, even if its not called "id".

Answer (score 12):

```
Blog.objects.filter(author=author).values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

Put `pk` instead `id`, just for best practices.

Answer (score 6):

[`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) it returns tuples when iterated over. Each tuple contains the value from the respective field or expression passed into the values_list().

```
author = Blog.objects.filter(author=author)
ids    = author.values_list('pk', flat=True)

# list method get ids without parse the returning queryset

print(list(ids))
```