# Django: Check if value exists in object.filter list

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my Django project I need to check whether a user submitted value exists in a list of values that is returned from the database via objects.filter().

User submitted data:

```
value = request.data['value_id']
```

Get valid status as ids:

```
allowed_values = Values.objects.filter(Q(code='Active') | Q(code='Inactive')).values('id')
```

This returns a queryset as follows.

> `<QuerySet [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]>`

Checking if user submitted value exists in the allowed_values:

```
if value in allowed_values:
    return True
```

But this does not work and I need allowed_values to return as a list of 'id's. How can I do this without iterating through allowed_values and creating a new list?

Comment: You mean that user submits data through an API? Then there are automatic way of doing what you want. Which libs are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django models: get list of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124549/django-models-get-list-of-id)

Comment: why not try to pull the data related to that `id` only, if no row returns then it is not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use values_list() method instead of values() method

```
 allowed_values = Values.objects.filter(Q(code='Active') | Q(code='Inactive')).values_list('id',flat=True)
```

Or, if you need only checking, you can use filter :

```
if Values.objects.filter(Q(code='Active') | Q(code='Inactive')).filter(id=value).count() > 0:
    return True
```

Comment: Values.objects.filter(Q(code='Active') | Q(code='Inactive'), id=value).exists()

Answer (score 1):

use `values_list('id', flat=True)` instead `.values('id')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists), as simple as

```
allowed_values = Values.objects.filter(...).exists()
```

This will return True if the QuerySet contains any results.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you can write solve it as below logic...

```
allowed_values = Values.objects.filter(Q(code='Active') | Q(code='Inactive')).values('id')
allowed_values_list = list(allowed_values)

for id_dict in allowed_values_list
    if value == id_dict['id']:
        return True
```